# Switching back to mac os from Ubuntu Problems

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, unix

A little while ago I switched my late 2015 Macbook Air to Ubuntu (not dual boot) because I needed a linux computer for work. I overwrote the existing os because it was taking up a massive amount of the storage space and i said "I can always just use a bootable usb to switch back if i dont like Ubuntu". This might have been stupid, but it made sense at the time. There have been issues with Ubuntu and I like it less in general, and no longer need it for work, so I am trying to switch back to mac os. I tried booting the computer in Internet Recovery mode by holding Command + R and selected the Reinstall OSX option and went through the steps until I got to the part where you select the disk to install it on. Normally I think there would be an option called Macintosh HD there, but it is currently empty, as you can see in the attached image.
I also should mention that I have a bootable usb with High Sierra on it that I made with my other computer, and when I plug it in, and boot the computer while holding the option key and follow the necessary steps I get the same problem, where the hard drive is not visible, and only the bootable usb is shown. Is it possible that when I installed Ubuntu I overwrote the Macintosh HD? Is there any hope of getting back to mac os? Any help is appreciated.

> Note: My Mac has a single internal SSD.

[image]

Comment: When you get to Recovery, first thing you will need to do is reformat the HD, GUID/HFS+ from Disk Utilities.

Comment: Okay, I have booted again with Command + R and opened the disk utility. I see an one Internal drive called APPLE SSD SM0128G Media. Is that the one I need to be reformatting? And how do I do this? Sorry, I just don't want to mess it up and go from bad to worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you installed Ubuntu, you overwrote the partition named `Macintosh HD`. You will need to recreate this partition before installing macOS (OS X).

You can use the Disk Utility application to erase your drive. For name, use `Macintosh HD`. For the format, use either `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` or `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)`.

Sometimes when the previous operating system was Linux, this can fail. If so, perform the steps given below.

1. From the menu bar, select `Utilities→Terminal`.
2. In the Terminal windows enter the following commands.

   ```
   diskutil  unmountdisk  disk0
   diskutil  erasedisk  jhfs+  "Macintosh HD"  GPT  disk0
   ```
3. Quit the Terminal application.
4. If you want encryption, use the Disk Utility application to erase the drive again.
5. Install macOS (OS X).

Note: If you install or upgrade to High Sierra and your internal drive is a SSD, then this drive will probably to converted to use the new Apple File System (APFS) format.

Comment: Thank you, this appears to have worked! Just out of curiosity, do you know why this is required? Did Ubuntu reformat the hard drive when it was installed?

Comment: There are may ways to install Ubuntu, all require creating new formatted partitions. It is even possible that a working macOS (OS X) is still exists on your Mac. At this point you, it would be best to remove all partitions, create new partitions, format the partitions and install a clean copy of macOS (OS X).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if i run into any issues with this install. When I installed Ubuntu I just used a bootable usb, and chose the overwrite existing os option. Wouldn't it only preserve the old os if I had tried to do a dual boot?

Comment: My mistake. You did state you overwrote the previous operating system when you installed Ubuntu.